# How do I get the monthName to display?

Tags: java, calendar

Here is my code:

```
public class CalendarDisplay {

  public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)
  {
    return (year %400 == 0) ||
            (year %4 == 0 && year %100 != 0);

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int year = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(args [1]);
    boolean leapYear = isLeapYear(year);
    System.out.println("The Year " + year + ((leapYear == true)?
            " is": " is not") + " a leap year");
    int days = 0;

    switch(month)
    {
        case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11:
            days=30;
        case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10: case 12:
            days = 31;
        case 2:
            days = (leapYear == true)? 29:28;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println ("error!");
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("The Month " + month + " has " + days);    
  }

  public static String getMonthName (int month) {
    String monthName = "";    
        switch(month)
        {
            case 1:
                monthName = "January";
                break;
            case 2:
                monthName = "Feburary";
                break;
            case 3:
                monthName = "March";
                break;
            case 4:
                monthName = "April";
                break;
            case 5:
                monthName = "May";
                break;
            case 6:
                monthName = "June";
                break;
            case 7:
                monthName = "July";
                break;
            case 8:
                monthName = "August";
                break;
            case 9:
                monthName = "September";
                break;
            case 10:
                monthName = "October";
                break;
            case 11:
                monthName = "November";
                break;
            case 12:
                monthName = "December";
                break;
        }
        return monthName;

  }

}
```

at the command line I input:  2014 02

The output is this:

"The Year 2014 is not a leap year
The Month 2 has 28"

I need "Month 2" to say "Month February"

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried calling `getMonthName` and displaying the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `getMonthName` function returns a String value, your `System.out.println` can call the `getMonthName` method and use the result as part of the output.

```
System.out.println("The Month " + getMonthName(month) + " has " + days + " days");
```